# VS Code Run Flutter Failed to build iOS app on Mac M1 Pro

Tags: ios, flutter, visual-studio-code

I am getting this error on Mac M1 when i run flutter app in VS Code.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro Max in debug mode...
main.dart:1
Xcode build done.                                            2.9s
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): Target debug_unpack_ios failed: Exception: Binary 
<My Path to Flutter source>flutter_application_test/build/ios/Debug- 
iphonesimulator/Flutter.framework/Flutter does not exist, cannot thin

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.
Exited
```

Answer (score 0):

this will be working for this problem.

```
sudo softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license
```